# Delete from firebase using a recyclerview android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up a RecyclerViewAdapter and I can add posts to this perfectly fine but within firebase i have only defined a collection not a document and so firebase generates a random string, I can get the string details but I do not know how to co-ordinate that with the recyclerview so that when i swipe to delete it gets the revelant string and deletes that from the firebase, currently it just takes the latest one created and deletes that.

[firebase database string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ybu.png)
[My app showing the same reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paaFl.jpg)
As you can see i can get the String value and i even store it as a field using getters and setters but i do not know how to reference that back in order to delete the correct document.

My object is created in one activity (ACTIVITY 1) and displayed within another (ACTIVITY 2).

Activity 1:

```
filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

   filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
   String imageUrl = uri.toString(); //creates a URL that links to the images


   final Journal journal = new Journal();
   journal.setTitle(title);
                                journal.setDescription(description);
                                journal.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
                                journal.setTimeAdded(new Timestamp(new Date()));
                                journal.setUsername(currentUserName);
                                journal.setUserId(currentUserId);
                                journal.setDocRef(documentId);

                            JournalApi.getInstance().setDocRef(journal.getDocRef());
                            collectionReference.document(documentId).set(journal).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {


@Override
 public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
postJournalProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
Intent intent = new Intent(PostJournalActivity.this, JournalListActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(PostJournalActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: when saving the journal" + e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                });
                                //save a journal instance
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

}
});
}
});
}}
```

Activity 2:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        collectionReference.whereEqualTo("userId", JournalApi
                .getInstance()
                .getUserId())
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot journals : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                /**/
                                journal = journals.toObject(Journal.class);
                                journalList.add(journal);

                                docList.add(journal.getDocRef());


                            }
                            journalRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(JournalListActivity.this, journalList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(journalRecyclerViewAdapter);
                            journalRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            noJournalEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                }
            });

}



//Swipe To Delete
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback swipeToDelete = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            //removes the data from the recyclerview and adds corrects the screen accordingly
            journalList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        journalRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        journalRecyclerViewAdapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

        deleteItem();
    }
};

private void deleteItem() {

    collectionReference.document(testDocumentId).set(journal);


    db.collection("Journal")
            .document(testDocumentId)
            .delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(JournalListActivity.this, "Deleted?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(JournalListActivity.this, "NOPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I can reference the recyclerview adapter in order to remove the view from the phone and update correctly but once i refresh it just comes back because i cannot remove from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you do two things when you get the documents from Firestore in your query's `onSuccess` handler:

1. You add the data of the document to `journalList` as a `Journal`
2. You add the reference to the document to `docList`

This means that when you remove the `Journal` from the `journalList` by its position, you can also get/remove the reference from `docList` and remove the document from Firestore.

The code should look something like this:

```
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    collectionReference.document(docList.get(position)).delete();
    docList.remove(position).delete();
    journalList.remove(position);
    journalRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    journalRecyclerViewAdapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}
```

Comment: the .delete method does not exist, and there are no other options to select from that are revelant, i can't add a pic to here to show (or at least i don't know how to). My journal is set as follows:  private List<Journal> journalList = new ArrayList<>();  private List docList = new ArrayList();

Comment: Interesting. I assumed you store [`DocumentReference` objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) in `docList`, they should have a `delete()` method. If you check in a debugger what `docList.get(position)`, is it a `DocumentReference`? I guess that's the same question as: what does `journal.getDocRef()` return?

Comment: i called it docRef because it was to hold the string reference of the document in firebase, but i understand your logic as there is a DocumentReference method for firebase. If you look at my original code youll see that below is the actual delete method so what i am trying now (based of your code) is to do .remove(position) after the deleteItem();

Comment: If `docList.get(position)` contains the key of the document, you can delete it by creating a new `DocumentReference` based on the reference to the collection and that key. I updated my answer to show that. Note that you can get the ID of a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` with [`journals.getId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getId()).

Comment: DUDEEEEE... thank you. I have been working on this for like 2 weeks and i just couldn't figure it out. I know how to delete if i create the document reference because i know what it's called but i couldn't figure out a random string. Thank you.

Comment: hey... me again, just a quick one, I am trying to do the same for images (storage reference) and although i am able to get the gs:// URL with my reference at the end when i do a .delete() i get no errors and it deletes from my imageRef array but not from firebase. -->   private StorageReference myReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(); -->             myReference.child(String.valueOf(imageRef.get(position))); --> myReference.delete(); --> If you would like this in a new post i understand. I have searched and found similar issues but couldn't implement successfully.